# Advantage of computed properties (gettable ones only) vs. stored properties

Tags: swift, properties

I would like to clarify if I understand the following concept correctly.

Assume that my goal is to store the `String` `"Good morning, Mike"` into the variable `var sayGoodMorningToUser`.

The String is composed of two variables, namely

```
var greeting = "Good morning, "
var username = "Mike"
```

What difference does it make if I use stored properties vs. computed properties, in other words:

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = greeting + username
```

vs.

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserComputed:String {
     return greeting + username
}
```

The only difference I see between these two approaches is that anyone could change the value of sayGoodMorningToUserStored easily and directly, e.g. by writing

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = "myNewChangedValue"
```

whereas the variable sayGoodMorningToUserComputed cannot be modified directly, because it cannot simply be set it to a new String value:

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserComputed = "Hallo" //this would cause an error
```

Otherwise I cannot understand why people compute the variable instead of simply writing

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = greeting + username.
```

Can anyone explain if I understood it correctly? Or are there also other advantages of computed variables vs. stored ones?

I would like to limit my question to gettable variables only, because discussing settable variables here would go beyond the scope.

Comment: The purpose of the computed property is that you declare it once, and when the `username` changes, the computed "greeting" property would automatically be updated to reflect that. So if the `username` changed, you don't have to remember to go update `sayGoodMorningToUserStored`, too. If you reference it elsewhere in your code, it will automatically reflect the then-current value of `username` rather than the `username` as-it-was when `sayGoodMorningToUserStored` was first declared.

Comment: The main difference I can think of right now is with protocols and protocol extensions. With protocols cannot hold state, so a computed value is best.

Comment: @Pisan if you feel your question has been satisfied, please rate mark a question as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Computed Properties

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserComputed: String {
     return greeting + username
}
```

`sayGoodMorningToUserComputed` acts just like a function. If a change has been made to `greeting` or `username`, then `sayGoodMorningToUserComputed` will return an up-to-date result that will be the concatenation of the current values.

You would want to use this if you want to ensure your returned value is computed off the latest values of its dependencies (`greeting` and `username`).

In the case that both dependencies are `final`, then it's very likely that the compiler would optimise this computed property into a stored property, because it knows the dependencies can't change

## Stored properties

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = greeting + username
```

`sayGoodMorningToUserStored` is just a variable, with nothing special going on. However, it's only set once, whenever the containing scope is initialized. It's computed once, stored and remains constant until it is overwritten by an external source. As such, if `greeting` or `username` changes, there will be no effect on `sayGoodMorningToUserStored`, because it's been computed from the old values, and stored.

You would want to use this if you want to improve performance by caching the result of a computation whose dependencies are constant.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in your example is this:

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = "myNewChangedValue"
```

and

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserStored = greeting + username
```

are set when your class is initialized, whereas this:

```
var sayGoodMorningToUserComputed:String {
     return greeting + username
}
```

is evaluated every time the property is accessed.

The simple example is a class that has a `firstName` and `lastName`, but also want `fullName`. Using a normal property, every time you update `firstName` or `lastName` you will also have to update `fullName` so it will match. Using a computed property, every time you access `fullName` you will get the up to date information.