# Difference between variables

Tags: swift, variables

Currently I'm trying to learn Swift. But I don't understand the difference between

```
var a : String {return "some text"}
```

and

```
var b : String = "some text"
```

What's the first code example for and when do I use it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981781/advantage-of-computed-properties-gettable-ones-only-vs-stored-properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second variable `var b` is declared as a *[stored property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255)*:

> In its simplest form, a stored property is a constant or variable that
>   is stored as part of an instance of a particular class or structure.
>   Stored properties can be either variable stored properties (introduced
>   by the var keyword) or constant stored properties (introduced by the
>   let keyword).

You could consider it as the default way for declaring properties.

The first variable `var a` is declared as a *[computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259)*:

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and
>   enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually
>   store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter
>   to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

You should declare a computed property when you need to edit the value of a stored property or even getting a new type based on another stored property.

Example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    // stored properties
    var var1: Int
    var var2: Int

    // comupted properties
    var multiplication: Int {
        return var1 * var2
    }

    var result: String {
        return "result is: \(multiplication)"
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that computed properties do *not* store the value, instead it just acts like a regular function that returns a value of a type.

Also, you could treat the computed property as a *getter-setter* for your -private- stored properties, example:

```
struct AccessControlStruct {
    private var stored: String

    var computed: String {
        get {
            return stored
        }

        set {
            stored = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        }
    }
}
```

Since `stored` declared as private, the only way is to access from out of the structure scope is by setting/getting its value by talking to `computed`. Obviously, you could any desired edit to the value before setting/getting it to/from `stored`, as an example, I am letting the newValue string of the `computed` to be trimmed before setting it to `stored`, it is also possible to edit the value before getting it.

---

**Reference:**

For more information, I would suggest to review:

[The Swift Programming Language - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration is what is being called a *computed property*. You can use it if the valuable’s value is the result of a calculation. In your example, however, it doesn’t make sense to use one. Here’s an example that should give you the idea:

```
var fullName: String { return firstName + " " + lastName }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But can't I do something like var fullname = firstname + " " + lastname? I would be much easier in my opinion